# How to use an Angular Material Slider with FormControl in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, slider

I want to use an Angular Material Slider with an FormControl within a FormGroup. I have a list with predefined values and for each of the I have a slider. The list consists of an array with objects, and every object has an id and an title:

```
const array = [{id: 'anyId', title: 'theTitle'}, ...]
```

I need to handle a title of the slider and the value of the slider because I have many sliders.

So I have objects like:

```
{id: 'anyId', value: 'sliderValue'}
```

```
<mat-list>
              <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of array">{{item.title}}
                <mat-slider step="1" min="0" max="4" thumbLabel></mat-slider>
              </mat-list-item>
            </mat-list>
```

How can I manage this with a formControl?
The FormControl should set the current value to the slider and save the new value of the slider - both to the correct title of the array list.

Answer (score 6):

```
<mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Modification Value</mat-label>
            <input #modValue type="number" [formControl]="modificationValue" matInput required>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-slider [value]="modValue.value" (change)="modValue.value = $event.value"></mat-slider>
```

try to map @Input()value and @Output()change from slider to your input element.
I think it is also possible to to use it like this:

```
<mat-slider [value]="modificationValue.value" (change)="modificationValue.setValue($event.value)"></mat-slider>
```

Answer (score 5):

### Angular Material 15

I recently updated to Angular Material 15 (which was a lot of work) and `mat-slider` is one of the controls with the greatest changes, that tripped me up the most:

If you did it wrong (like me) you may see an error like this:

`ERROR Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control unspecified name attribute. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG01203`

The [new way to use a slider](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview) is like this:

```
<mat-slider min="1" max="5" step="0.5" value="1.5">
  <input matSliderThumb>
</mat-slider>
```

So all you need to do is add `[formControl]` to the `<input>` like this:

```
<input matSliderThumb [formControl]="form.controls.numberOfDogs" />
```

(or `formControlName` if you prefer)

Answer (score -4):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4uwzsd

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of array">{{item.title}}
        <mat-slider [thumbLabel]="true" [(ngModel)]="item.value"></mat-slider>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

item.value should be a number!
Here you can find official examples: https://material.angular.io/components/slider/examples

Comment: how to use this with a FormControl?